# Android cannot link *.so lib

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, linker-errors

I newbie in Android and required me to create an app with functions in C++, they gave the *.so files.

I put the *.so files in the next directory:

```
src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   ├── jniLibs
│       │   │   ├── armeabi
│       │   │   │   ├── libjni_lib1.so
│       │   │   │   ├── libjni_lib2.so
│       │   │   │   ├── libjni_libn.so
```

Y load it in this way:

```
static {
   System.loadLibrary("jni_lib1");
}
```

But when I debug the application, get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.cloudpos.jniinterface.SmartCardInterface.smartcardInit:()I
                  at com.cloudpos.jniinterface.SmartCardInterface.smartcardInit(Native Method)
                  at cr.pf.com.controller.SmartCardController.searchBegin(SmartCardController.java:57)
                  at cr.pf.com.cr.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:134)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5364 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

I have already read how to add *.so files, and only says that put all them in jniLibs folders, how can I do?

Comment: 1) .apk files are zip files, rename your apk file and unzip it to see if the .so files made it into the apk file.  2) Please show the .h and .c/c++ file that has `smartcardInit(...)`. 3) Java loadLibrary does not load dependant .so files,  you need to load the most dependant .so file 1st, then the next most dependant .so file etc.

Comment: I have already done that, and I have seen libraries in lib folder, what else can I do?

Comment: So, did you manage to di it?

Answer (score 0):

If loadLibrary() did not throw exception, your so files are most likely installed correctly. I would still add log stttement after `loadLibrary()` - only to be sure this static constructor was executed as and when expected.

Often, errors similar to the one you saw happen with prebuilt so libraries, when the native method signatures do not match, typically because the package name assumed by the native library is not the same as used in Java app.

This may happen because Android encourages us to use the Java package same as the application package name, as specified in the manifest. But you are free to use any Java package name for any of your classes.

You can use `nm` command, which is distributed with NDK, to analyze the actual names of exported functions of the **.so**, and the expected Java package may be derived from that.